# Insert/join table on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I’ve a table that looks like this:

```
Table A

Version,id
5060586,22285

5074515,22701
5074515,22285

7242751,22701
7242751,22285
```

I want to generate a new key called groupId that is inserted as my example below:

```
Table A

Version,id,groupId
5060586,22285,1

5074515,22701,2
5074515,22285,2

7242751,22701,2
7242751,22285,2
```

I want the groupId to be the same as long as the id's are the same in the different versions. So for example version 5074515 and 7242751 has the same id's so therefor the groupId will be the same. If all the id's aren't the same a new groupId should be added as it has in version 5060586.

How can i solve this specific problem in SQL oracle?

Comment: `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY version,id) AS groupId` would already satisfy your case depending on the current data. Perhaps, you might try to change the sample data set if you need more.

Comment: Is it possible to add a custom id as groupId? for example SELECT MAX(PK) + 1 FROM C) + ROWNUM AS PK 

@BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a unique value representing the set of ids in each version, then assign a groupid to the unique values of *that*, then join back to the original data.

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO t (version,id) VALUES (5060586,22285)
INTO t (version,id) VALUES (5074515,22701)
INTO t (version,id) VALUES (5074515,22285)
INTO t (version,id) VALUES (7242751,22701)
INTO t (version,id) VALUES (7242751,22285)
SELECT 1 FROM dual;

WITH groups
AS
(
SELECT version
, LISTAGG(id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS group_text
FROM t
GROUP BY version
),
groupids
AS
(
SELECT group_text, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY group_text) AS groupid
FROM groups
GROUP BY group_text
)
SELECT t.*, groupids.groupid
FROM t
    INNER JOIN groups ON t.version = groups.version
    INNER JOIN groupids ON groups.group_text = groupids.group_text;
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b2fde203f49413b8cf8b5ac3609176bf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
UPDATE tableA t
SET group_id = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
                 FROM   TableA x
                 WHERE  x.Version <= t.version );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableA (
  Version  NUMBER,
  id       NUMBER,
  group_id NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO TableA (Version, id)
SELECT 5060586,22285 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5074515,22701 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5074515,22285 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7242751,22701 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7242751,22285 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the update:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tablea;
```

Outputs:

> | VERSION | ID | GROUP_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 5060586 | 22285 | 1 |
> | 5074515 | 22701 | 2 |
> | 5074515 | 22285 | 2 |
> | 7242751 | 22701 | 2 |
> | 7242751 | 22285 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=86bda07a7c296954f541a5d8aa5c1066)*

Comment: Is it possible to add a custom id as groupId? for example 

SELECT MAX(PK) + 1 FROM C) + ROWNUM AS PK